# Explicit cast required in ConsoleApplication2.Indicatordata

Tags: c#

I am trying to query the List with multiple values. I get a cast exception that I don't understand why. what should I cast in my "From" query?

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'ConsoleApplication2.Indicatordata'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Indicatordata> Indicator = new List<Indicatordata>();

     public static List<DTNBars> getDTNBars(string symbol, DateTime dt)
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\MarketData\" + symbol + ".txt", FileMode.Open));
        List<DTNBars> dtnbars = new List<DTNBars>();
        DTNBars b = null;
        CsvReader csvr = new CsvReader(tr);
        DateTime prevDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        while (csvr.Read())
        {
            b = new DTNBars();

            b.Date_Time = csvr.GetField<DateTime>(0);
            if (USMarketHours(b.Date_Time)){
                if (prevDateTime == DateTime.MinValue || prevDateTime.Date != b.Date_Time.Date)
                {
                    // new date.
                    b.isNewDay = true;
                    prevDateTime = b.Date_Time.Date;
                    Indicatordata yesterday = from   id in Indicator
                                              where id.Ticker == symbol
                                                &&   id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                                              select id;



                }
                if (b.Date_Time >= dt)
                {
                    b.Open = csvr.GetField<double>(1);
                    b.High = csvr.GetField<double>(2);
                    b.Low = csvr.GetField<double>(3);
                    b.Close = csvr.GetField<double>(4);
                    b.Ticker = symbol;

                    dtnbars.Add(b);
                }
            }
        }
        tr.Close();
        return dtnbars.OrderBy(x => x.Date_Time).ToList<DTNBars>();
    }  
}

// class specification.

class Indicatordata
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_Time { get; set; }
    public double? Close { get; set; }
    public double? Range { get; set; }
    public double? DAILYCCI { get; set; }
    public double? MA9 { get; set; }
    public double? MA50 { get; set; }
    public int? dailyVolume { get; set; }
    public double? Open { get; set; }
    public double? High { get; set; }
    public double? Low { get; set; }
    public bool? HH7 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I updated the method with all the details as I had only posted a skeleton before. the getDTNBars does return a list. The error is only isolated to the "Select" section of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Indicatordata yesterday = Indicator.FirstOrDefault(id => id.Ticker == symbol && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime);
```

You can also use this but I don't personally like it:

```
Indicatordata yesterday = (from   id in Indicator
                           where  id.Ticker == symbol   && 
                                  id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                           select id).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit**

`FirstOrDefault` is what I normally use in my code for most cases.
As others have suggested using `Single`, I wanted to add that `Single` will throw an exception if there are more than one matches and it will throw an exception if no match is found.
Using `SingleOrDefault` will also throw an `IllegalOperation` exception when more than match is found but not when none is.

Usually `FirstOrDefault` is faster than `SingleOrDefault` because it return the first match it finds unlike `SingleOrDefault` which iterates over the entire collection to check for another match.
If you consider having more than one match an issue, you should instead use `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: what would be the default value if it does not find a row? would it return a  null object?

Answer (score 2):

You are using LINQ to filter out records. `where` returns an `IEnumarable`. Specifically in your case an `IEnumarable<Indicatordata>`.

So either change it to:

```
IEnumarable<Indicatordata> yesterday = from id in Indicator
                                  where id.Ticker == symbol
                                    && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                                  select id;
```

Or just use `var`.

If you're sure you have one result then use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

```
var yesterday = (from id in Indicator
                where id.Ticker == symbol
                         && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                select id).Single();
```

Or use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` to get the first element in the sequence

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Indicatordata yesterday = from id in Indicator
                          where id.Ticker == symbol
                           && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                          select id;
```

returns not just one value, but IEnumerable, so if you want just one of it you may do smth like:

```
Indicatordata yesterday = Indicator.Where(id => id.Ticker == symbol
                           && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime)
                           .Select(id => id)
                           .Single();
```

Or it may be First/SingleOrDefault/FirstOrDefault depends on data logic

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ query returns an `IEnumerable<Indicatordata>` because the compiler has no way of knowing that your data will return a single instance based on the criteria you have supplied.  Your LINQ query should be:

```
Indicatordata yesterday = (from   id in Indicator
                           where  id.Ticker == symbol
                              &&  id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                           select id).FirstOrDefault();
```

and it will return what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your query returns a `collection` of your `IndicatorData` and you are trying put that value in one 'IndicatorData' object. That is the problem.

You could either take 1 object from your query or assign it `IEnumerable<IndicatorData>` or better yet use `var`.

Take one object from the returned collection by:

```
Indicatordata yesterday = (from id in Indicator
                           where id.Ticker == symbol
                           && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                           select id).FirstOrDefault();
//be sure to do your null checks, result will be null if no match is found.
```

or accept the returned collection:

```
List<Indicatordata> yesterdayIndicators = (from id in Indicator
                               where id.Ticker == symbol
                               && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                               select id).ToList();
```

alternative, use `var` keyword:

```
var yesterdayIndicators = (from id in Indicator
                               where id.Ticker == symbol
                               && id.Date_Time.Date == prevDateTime
                               select id).ToList();
```